# Searching for recently created folders yields no result

Tags: box-api

I am able to successfully create a folder within the root of my Box account via the v2 API. However, if I immediately issue a search request for it, I get no results. If I wait for some period of time (maybe 20 mins) and then issue the search request, the folder I created is returned.

Is there some cacheing going on on the Box side? If so, is there a way to invalidate the cache via the API or some workaround for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is going on is background backend processing of your file.  Just like a new website won't show up in a google search until Google has time to 'learn' about the new website, Box's search engine has to process the file and add the text version of the contents to the Box search engine.  Exactly how long it takes to be added depends on a lot of variables, including the size and format of the file.

You'll see pretty much the same behavior if you upload a large document to Box and then try to preview it immediately.   Box goes off and does some magic to convert your file to a previewable format.  Except in the case of the preview, the Box website gives you a little bit of feedback saying "Generating preview."  The search bar doesn't tell you "adding new files to search index."

This is mostly because it is more important for Box to get your file and make sure we store it safely and let you know that Box has it.  A few milliseconds later on we start working on processing your file for full text search and all the other processing that we do.